# Could not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions'

Tags: android, firebase

I have a working app and everything was working well, but when I updated it with `MoPub` app and generated a new signed APK and uploaded it to the play store some users reported a crash while it works well on other users' devices.

I tested the app a lot on different devices and finally found a device that it crashed on.

I debugged the app and found this error code in the android monitor

> 06-18 16:17:51.665 17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser;) 06-18 16:17:51.665
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zza', referenced from method
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza 06-18 16:17:51.665
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve check-cast 9003 (Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$zza;) in
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; 06-18 16:17:51.665
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x1f at 0x0019 06-18 16:17:51.665
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   opt direct call 0xec65 at 0x0b in
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;.getToken 06-18 16:17:51.665
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 06-18 16:17:51.665 17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41bdc700) 06-18 16:17:51.685
>   17951-17951/akhbar4all.com.akhbar4all E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5119)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4725)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4665)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

But I was shocked because I didn't use any `Firebase api` so why is this happening and what is the solution? I'd be happy for any help from someone.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved the problem.

The problem was that their is an error in firebase including latest google play services 9.0.2

So i choose only the google play services that i need and not the whole services excluding (firebase) and everything works well

To setup google services by what you need and don't include the whole services visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: you are great, you saved my valuable time.

Comment: Thanks, I had also compiled the multidex class to solve my problem but it made my application a little heavier, now it is better optimized!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I had also compiled the multidex class to solve my problem but it made my application a little heavier, now it is better optimized!

This is to compile only the google services that you are going to use and not all with the compile statement `'com.google.android.gms: play-services: 9.0.0'`

Now my gradle file looks like this

```
//compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
```